# Lazy superclass evaluation

Tags: python

I need to define a class `MyClass` within a developed package. The class `MyClass` should inherit from another class, from an external library `ext_lib.Class`. So the situation I want to achieve is:

```py
class MyClass(ext_lib.Class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

However, there is a trick to be done here. I want my package to work without `ext_lib`. It should be required iff a user wants to create a `MyClass` instance

I tried to use meta class:

```py
class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        import ext_lib
        bases += (ext_lib.Class,)
        new_cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return new_cls


class MyClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

However, I still have an error that the `ext_lib` is not installed before initialization.

Do you have any hint how to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: The thing is that I need to define a class that inherits from the class from an external library. This is not compatible with what you propose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__new__` method of a metaclass is called when a class object using the metaclass is created when the class statement is executed, so the `import` statement is effectively executed unconditionally with this approach.

A workaround is to use a function that dynamically creates the class only when called:

```
def MyClass(*args, **kwargs):
    import ext_lib

    class _MyClass(ext_lib.Class):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass
    
    return _MyClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That breaks the usual type checking and accessing the class object though…

Comment: Yes, but it may still satisfy many use cases. Virtually all client classes in AWS's `boto3` package are dynamically created like that, for example, while still serving the purpose well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a simple conditional declaration like this:

```
try:
    import ext_lib

    class MyClass(ext_lib.Class):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

except ImportError:
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self):
            raise NotImplementedError('ext_lib is not installed')
```

If you don't like having the class definition all indented in an `if` block, you can also just put it in another file (I'd suggest `_my_class.py`) and do:

```
try:
    from ._my_class import MyClass
except ImportError:
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self):
            raise NotImplementedError('ext_lib is not installed')
```

Comment: You are right, it works, but I prefer the second proposed answer. For me, it's much more clear and type checking for me and this particular use-case is not that important. Anyway, thank you!